# Change location of sys.stderr for wsgi and apache?

Tags: apache2, mod-wsgi, stderr

I am logging Apache2 errors in a custom location (i.e. not /var/log/apache2/error.log) using the following line in httpd.conf:

```
ErrorLog /custom/path/to/error.log
```

However, when I use mod_wsgi to serve a django application, the stderr output from that still gets dumped to /var/log/apache2/error.log.

My apache2 errors get dumped in the custom location, but my python errors still get dumped in the default location. How do I get everything to dump in the custom location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you want you need to be using mod_wsgi daemon mode. Plus, the WSGIDaemonProcess/WSGIProcessGroup directives need to be specified within the VirtualHost where you have specified the ErrorLog directive. Finally you need to be using mod_wsgi 3.0+ and not the now quite old mod_wsgi 2.0+ that some Linux distributions still provide.

Satisfy those conditions and you still can't get it going then post the problem to the mod_wsgi mailing list.

Comment: Yes, this works. I added the two WSGIDaemonProcess and WSGIProcessGroup lines from the [example docs](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#Delegation_To_Daemon_Process) for mod_wsgi. Thanks!